# Restore package failed for `Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation` in asp.net 5 rc1-final

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx

I am using `Dnx` compilation engine to compile a c# package class library.but when i add a reference to preceding package in `project.json`file i end up with following message :

> The dependency `Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation` 1.0.0-rc1-final in project
>   [x] doest not support framework .Net Framework Version v4.5.1

But i toke a look at `DNX` source code and saw a reference for `framework v4.5.1` there.following picture is an evidence for what i've mentioned.

[image: Dnx project referencing full framework]

Any idea why this happens?

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Tourism.Framework Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Behnam" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Autofac": "4.0.0-rc1-177",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "AutoMapper": "4.1.1",
    "log4net": "2.0.4",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation" : "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation) package targets DNX 4.5.1 (`dnx451`) and DNX Core 5.0 (`dnxcore50`) as it requires DNX. It does **not** target the standard, full .NET framework v4.5.1 (`net451`).

If you want to use it, you should target `dnx451` in your project.json. This is the preffered target framework: Apps should target `dnx451` and *class libraries* should target `net451` (see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98)).

Comment: thanks for you'r quick response.could you explain difference between  `net451` & `dnx451`.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili I just did: `dnx451` is for applications, `net451` for class libraries. Also see the issue on the Announcements repo I mentioned.